# Add target to all UIButtons' touchUpInside Event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrolevents

I hope that this question's answer is as simple as the question itself.

I have a sound effect in an AVAudioPlayer that I want to play when *every* button is pressed. Now rather than manually adding a target to play that audio file to ***every*** button in my code, is there a way where I can override the touchUpInside event method (perhaps in an extension category file) and send the call to the AVPlayer in addition to sending the call to the super?

I don't want to have to subclass if I don't have to. Is there a delegate method I can use?

Comment: Overriding base class methods in a category file are usually bad form

Comment: Can you suggest another way?

Comment: Sure, create a subclass that adds the target in whichever init you see fit.

Comment: Do you think that adding an init method in the category that overrides the `initWithFrame:` method and adds the target would work? Or is that bad practice?

Comment: @David, I agree with 0x7ffffff. You can shift+select all of the buttons in the nib or storyboard and set the subclass on all of them at once.

Comment: But I'm not using IB... All buttons are added in code, which is why I wanted a solution that didn't involve me adding the same line of code to 100 buttons.

Comment: Are they added in a loop or individually? If you have 100 buttons with some commonality you should definitely be subclassing anyways.

Comment: Well this is the only thing I have needed to add to the base UIButton class. Almost every button is added individually, except for a few here and there in the menus. I didn't see the need to subclass something that I didn't need to change.

Comment: It shouldn't be terribly difficult, just do a global find/replace on UIButton with your new subclass name. XCode will jump to every mention of UIButton and you can replace or skip it as needed. Just be sure to do a commit before the global replace!

Comment: I went ahead and did that. It seemed to be the most effective way to do it. Ah well, at least it works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any class that has a reference to the view which contains the buttons as subviews, you can just iterate through all of the subviews and see which ones are UIButtons:

```
for (id subview in _buttonView.subviews)
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        [(UIButton *)subview addTarget:self 
                             selector:@selector:(playSound)    
                             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, the best way is to subclass the parent view of your button view. If you are adding the buttons in a UIView class, then subclass your class from UIView. So, you will have to change only one place in the code.

Now, in the subclass override this method:

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview;
```

It will get called when any of the subviews will be added to it. Identify the proper subview in the method and do any processing over the subview which you want.